# MapReduce - reducer emits the output in one line

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a simple MapReduce job which is supposed to read a dictionary from a text file and them process another huge file line by line and compute the inverse document matrix. The output is supposed to look like this:

```
word-id1  docX:tfX docY:tfY
word-id2  docX:tfX docY:tfY etc...
```

However, the output of the reducer is emitted only in one huuuge line. I do not understand why since it should emit a new line for each `word-id` (which is the key for the reducer).

The mapper produces the correct output (pair of `word-id` and values of `doc-id:tf` on separate lines). I tested that without the reducer. The reducer is supposed to just append the values corresponding to the same key on one line for each key.

Could you please take a look on my code (specifically on the reducer and configuration of the job) and tell me why does the reducer emit only one huge line instead of multiple lines corresponding to the specified keys? I spent many hours debugging this and cannot make my head around it.

```
public class Indexer extends Configured implements Tool {

    /*
     * Vocabulary: key = term, value = index
     */
    private static Map<String, Integer> vocab = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws Exception {
        System.exit(ToolRunner.run(new Indexer(), arguments));
    }

    public static class Comparator extends WritableComparator {
        protected Comparator() {
            super(Text.class, true);
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(WritableComparable a, WritableComparable b) {
            // Here we use exploit the implementation of compareTo(...) in
            // Text.class.
            return -a.compareTo(b);
        }
    }

    public static class IndexerMapper extends
            Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
        private Text result = new Text();

        // load vocab from distributed cache
        public void setup(Context context) throws IOException {
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
            URI[] cacheFiles = DistributedCache.getCacheFiles(conf);
            Path getPath = new Path(cacheFiles[0].getPath());

            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    fs.open(getPath)));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " \t");

                int index = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); // first token is the line number - term id
                String word = st.nextToken(); // second element is the term

                // save vocab
                vocab.put(word, index);

            }
        }

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            // init TF map
            Map<String, Integer> mapTF = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            // parse input string
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), " \t");

            // first element is doc index
            int index = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

            // count term frequencies
            String word;
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word = st.nextToken();

                // check if word is in the vocabulary
                if (vocab.containsKey(word)) {
                    if (mapTF.containsKey(word)) {
                        int count = mapTF.get(word);
                        mapTF.put(word, count + 1);
                    } else {
                        mapTF.put(word, 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            // compute TF-IDF
            int wordIndex;
            for (String term : mapTF.keySet()) {
                int tf = mapTF.get(term);

                if (vocab.containsKey(term)) {
                    wordIndex = vocab.get(term);

                    context.write(new IntWritable(wordIndex), new Text(index + ":" + tf));
                }

            }               
        }
    }

    public static class IndexerReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text>
    {
        @Override
        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(16000);

            for (Text value : values)
            {
                sb.append(value.toString() + " ");
            }


            context.write(key, new Text(sb.toString()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where the MapReduce job is configured and being launched.
     */
    @Override
    public int run(String[] arguments) throws Exception {
        ArgumentParser parser = new ArgumentParser("TextPreprocessor");

        parser.addArgument("input", true, true, "specify input directory");
        parser.addArgument("output", true, true, "specify output directory");

        parser.parseAndCheck(arguments);

        Path inputPath = new Path(parser.getString("input"));
        Path outputDir = new Path(parser.getString("output"));

        // Create configuration.
        Configuration conf = getConf();

        // add distributed file with vocabulary
        DistributedCache
                .addCacheFile(new URI("/user/myslima3/vocab.txt"), conf);

        // Create job.
        Job job = new Job(conf, "WordCount");
        job.setJarByClass(IndexerMapper.class);

        // Setup MapReduce.
        job.setMapperClass(IndexerMapper.class);
        //job.setCombinerClass(IndexerReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IndexerReducer.class);

        // Sort the output words in reversed order.
        job.setSortComparatorClass(Comparator.class);


        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        // Specify (key, value).
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        // Input.
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputPath);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

        // Output.
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputDir);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        // Delete output directory (if exists).
        if (hdfs.exists(outputDir))
            hdfs.delete(outputDir, true);

        // Execute the job.
        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you are getting different keys at mapper output ?? Also can you update sample output . Also just see in wordpad if you have delimeters, if your size of lines are very large you might overlook lines.

Comment: Yes, I am getting different keys from the mapper, that is confirmed... the output form mapper is  key [TAB] value

Comment: How did u confirm that your mapper output is correct ?? did u put number of reducers to 0 ? Also i think you need to cast the object in comparator ? Just try to remove custom comparator and see if it makes any change?

Comment: I ran the Mapper with 0 reducers as you guessed and checked that the output makes sense. Thanks for the tip with the comparator - I will try to remove it as soon as I get to it and post here how it went.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these to debug your issue -

- Put number of reducers to 0 and see what is the mapper output.
- Try using default comparator, also in your comparator you need to cast the objects, else they wont yield correct result.